# Raspberry Pi 4 between flight controller and receiver

Tags: quadcopters, flight-controller, ardupilot, raspberry-pi

I have TBS Crossfire Micro TX, Nano RX and Raspberry Pi 4, I haven't bought a flight controller yet because I have a problem:

Until the drone receives a special command from the transmitter - I control the drone in manual mode, but as soon as it is received, the Raspberry algorithm should control the drone.
I don’t know how to implement it, in what order to connect it all, so I’m asking for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. Hard way is to have special electronics to shift from the flight controller input to motors to the raspberry pi, but is very complicated.

The other way is to change flying mode on the flight controller so the raspberry does it job while disabling rc inputs. Look further into PX4

Comment: the first option is too complicated :)

but the second option, I didn’t quite understand how exactly to correlate the flight mode to raspberry

How about receiving data on the raspberry, processing it and sending it to the flight controller. As soon as the raspberry receives some kind of flag, apply an algorithm that will calculate the drone control itself

Comment: Check on PX4 the different flight modes. Px4 flight stack can already send the processed data on orientation, attitude, altitude for you to play with. Usually the raspberry pi control iut through the stabilized mode, so it is a controller wrap around and angle controller and you send orientation + thrust commands on the raspberry pi and the flight controller control the motor outputs based on the angle and thrust references. All communication is through RS232 on a Mavlink protocol

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer)